# Stock exchanges open on Saturday

Tags: stock-exchanges

I know that many Islamic countries have moved from their traditional Thu-Fri weekend to Fri-Sat setup to overlap with Western countries more while still having holiday on Friday. Because of this stock exchanges in those countries usually work from Sunday to Thursday. Are there any stock exchanges left which still use Saturday as a working day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tehran_Stock_Exchange) as well as [this stock market trading-hours website](https://www.stockmarketclock.com/exchanges/tse/trading-hours), the Tehran Stock Exchange is open Saturday through Wednesday.